# Handling multiple "AND"s and "OR"s using Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Is it possible to make a select like the following example using Eloquent ORM.

```
select .. where ... AND ( ( ... AND ...) OR ( ... AND  ... ))
```

Here is my "workaround" :

```
$tasks1=$user->Tasks()
->WhereBetween('start_date',array($start,$end))
->where('deleted',0)
->where('dated','=',1)
->where('status','=',$state)
->get();

$tasks2=$user->Tasks()
->WhereBetween('due_date',array($start,$end))
->where('deleted',0)
->where('dated','=',1)
->where('status','=',$state)
->get();

$tasks3=$user->Tasks()
->where('start_date','<',$start)
->where('due_date','>',$end)
->where('deleted',0)
->where('dated','=',1)
->where('status','=',$state)
->get();

$tasks = $tasks1->merge($tasks2);

$tasks = $tasks->merge($tasks3);
```

As you can see I am just running multiple queries using AND only, while merging them simulates the OR.

Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed perform grouped `and` `or` queries using Laravels Eloquent:

```
$tasks = Tasks::whereBetween('start_date', array($start,$end))
                ->where(function($query)
                {                    
                    ->where(function($q)
                    {
                        $q->where('column_a', 'foo')
                          ->where('column_b', 'bar');
                    })
                    ->orWhere(function($q)
                    {
                        $q->where('column_c', 'foo')
                          ->where('column_d', 'bar');
                    })
                })
                ->get();
```

This would produce a query like you were describing:

`SELECT ... WHERE ... AND ((... AND ...) OR (... AND ...))`

For more info about advanced where statements in Laravel check the docs here: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres

Comment: There is a missing curly `{` after `->where(function($query)` I think.
And "queries" instead of "querys".
Couldn't edit it myself, please do it.

Comment: Edited, glad you found it helpful :)